# How to change the font size in ipywidgets (dropdown, button, label...)

Tags: python, dropdown, font-size, ipywidgets

I just have a simple question about ipywidgets, how to increase the size of the name (description) of dropdowns, buttons, labels.

```
import IPython
import ipywidgets as widgets

html = "<h1 style='font-size:100px'> Test font  Test again </h1>"
widgets.HTML(value= html)


widgets.Button(description = 'abccc', button_style='danger')
widgets.Dropdown(description = 'asdasdf')
```

So the result of the first one widgets.HTML(value=html) comes out well, the size is big enough.

However, when what I want is to have a bigger size of the button / dropdown / label description.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W03Cp.png)

When you see the attached screenshot, the word is (personally) too small so I would like to increase the size of it.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank you so much! :)